# Lisp Horner's method using map-functions

Tags: lisp, polynomial-math, polynomials, map-function

Can [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) be implemented in lisp using `mapcan` or any other map function?
Here is my implementation without map functions:

```
(defun Horner (lst x)
    (cond
        ((null (cdr lst)) (car lst))
        (t 
            (Horner 
                (cons 
                    (+ (* (car lst) x) (cadr lst)) 
                    (cddr lst)
                ) 
                x
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The above code does not work, didn't you forget a `cond`?

Comment: @coredump Yes, sorry. I have to use muLisp and it works without cond on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it with map-like functions because they produce **lists** and
you need the result to be a **number**.

However, not all is lost --
[`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm) to the rescue!

```
(defun horner (polynomial x)
  (reduce (lambda (a b)
            (+ (* a x) b))
          polynomial :initial-value 0))
```

Note that this version also handles the 0 polynomial correctly: it
returns 0 when called as `(horner () 1)` (replace 1 with any number).
This glitch in your tail-recursive version is easily fixed:

```
(defun horner (polynomial x)
  (if (rest polynomial)
      (horner (cons (+ (* (first polynomial) x) (second polynomial))
                    (cddr polynomial))
              x)
      (or (first polynomial) 0)))
```

Comment: formally speaking, one could run a side-effecting lambda-function through a `(map 'nil ...)` call (reimplementing the `reduce`).